# WSO2 ESB: How to package axis archives within CAR archive

Tags: wso2-esb

Given a collection of aar files, How can I package them within a CAR?

Initial thought was to place each as a maven artifact into my Nexus, and explicitly add it as a dependency with the CAR pom but the CAR's pom GUI marks it as an error, and the developer studio actually deletes the lines.

I couldn't find a maven documentation for the car plugin other that that within the WSO2 manual, I thought there maybe a library option etc.

Is the bottom line that its not possible? Any other options?

Comment: Resolved: I picked up aar files as part of wso2 demo's. But they are actually deployed to axis servers, not to carbon server. So in the end, i think it is a non question.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the documentation below, which explains packaging aar using developer studio.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS380/Packaging+Artifacts+Into+Deployable+Archives

Comment: Thanks, I suspect that link refers to aar files as deployable units is there own right, not about packaging collections of aar's into a single car. I was trying to get away from having to deploy many artifacts, similar to a war file containing jars.